# How to directinize bluetooth signal?

Tags: bluetooth

I am creating a software. I have this http://estimote.com that is an iBeacon that transmit bluetooth signals. I know that bluetooth is omni directional but can I directinize it to one single direction? If yes, how can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to use a custom antenna and/or custom shielding. Either way is not really easy to do and there are mistakes to be made (especially when trying to do this on such small(?) scale). Worst case - and depending on where you live - you might even get problems with local authorities in case your signal becomes too strong and/or interferes with other things (although unlikely with such small devices).

There's no way to solve this issue in software.

However, depending on what you're trying to do (e.g. determining a direction), you might be able to use two of those stickers next to each other, so you could use triangulation.

Comment: As a software engineer I have very little knowlege about hardware and antennas. Quich question, Ive read some posts that says I could use a foil paper wrap around the bluetooth transmitting device and get a direction out of it.. Can this really work?

Comment: Yes, it could be as easy as that, essentially creating a reflector (similar to a classic satellite dish or tin foil hat if you want). You won't get any stronger signal just by wrapping tin foil around it though.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth uses radio waves for transmission. If you can create a directional radio wave device, and they do exist, you can create a directional bluetooth. You may wish to look at the electrical engineering stack exchange. This is not possible without different or modified hardware.

Here is an example where it appears someone is doing what you are asking: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/53674/adding-a-yagi-antenna-to-a-bluetooth-dongle

This example is regarding adding a yagi directional antenna to a bluetooth dongle.